# Getting `docker-compose run` to not do anything

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm making a devops script that runs

```
docker-compose run --no-deps my_service
```

For the sole reason of running diagnostic operations in the container, without running the actual container command. (Since it might be resource-intensive, or might fail altogether.)

I figured I'll override the entrypoint with some kind of no-op that runs forever.

The `runs forever` part is important, because if I'll just use `echo` or `cat` or anything, the process will finish immediately and I won't be able to use `docker exec` on my container.

I tried

```
--entrypoint "tail -f /dev/null"
```

But no luck. It seems that `--entrypoint` doesn't let you enter arguments for your command.

**Do you know whether that's supposed to be possible or not?**

Another funny hack I tried which kind of worked is `--entrypoint yes` which made the entrypoint be Linux's `yes` utility, which just output `y` in an infinite loop.  
This worked fine for 2 hours, until I ran out of harddrive space and had to delete everything.

If you've got an idea for a common Linux command like `yes` that just waits forever, and doesn't print an infinite amount of text, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `watch`?
This works:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM busybox

ENTRYPOINT ["echo","hello"]
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
```

Then:

```
$ docker-compose run --entrypoint="watch -n2 ls" test
```

[EDIT]: You can even set `-n` to 100000 if you don't want your container to do much... BTW, I tried with `tail -f /dev/null` and it seems to work, what is the version of docker-compose and docker?

Answer (score 0):

I use standard trick for development environment

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./:/srv/app:cached
```

The main part here is `command: tail -f /dev/null`.

Then you just `docker-compose up` and on the second terminal enter into it with `docker-compose exec app sh` (or `bash` instead of `sh`).

If you want to just run the container then just run is with `sh`/`bash`.

You can run it as `docker run --entrypoint tail -it elixir:alpine` as well if you need to redefine entrypoint and just "hang" it.